# Update statement data doesn't go into db

Tags: php, sql-update

```
//setting veriables
$imagestring = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$myuser = $_POST['myusername'];

//mysql set up error handle
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$chkuserid = mysql_query("select UserID from users where Username = '".$myuser."'"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($chkuserid); 
$finall = $row['UserID']; 
  // putting data into database
var_dump($finall);
$sql="UPDATE users SET avatarstring='k00138899.atspace.eu/photoalbum/upload/".$imagestring."' WHERE UserID='".$finall."'";
```

I think I tried everything in users table i have avatarstring which will store path to image if upload is successful

userid - int(25)
$finall - string
avatarstring - TEXT
File get uploaded but entry of the image address should go to avatarstring column along with this operation.



Code for uploading image works and this code is placed inside if statement if the upload is successfull this code is displayed along with message saying image upload successful

```
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "avatar/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "avatar/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

        // if upload successful add entry into DB
$host="fdb4.atspace.com:3306"; // Host name
$username="1259829_photo"; // Mysql username
$password="j8"; // Mysql password
$db_name="1259829_photo"; // Database name
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name

//setting veriables
$imagestring = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$myuser = $_POST['myusername'];

//mysql set up error handle
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$chkuserid = mysql_query("select UserID from users where Username = '".$myuser."'"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($chkuserid); 
$finall = $row['UserID']; 
  // putting data into database
var_dump($finall);
var_dump($myuser);

$sql="UPDATE users SET avatarstring='k00138899.atspace.eu/photoalbum/upload/".$imagestring."' WHERE Username='".$myuser."'";


      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Always use `mysqli_error`, will save you time debugging your queries

Comment: Don't you exec the update query ?

Comment: Where in your code do you save the image on your system ? And the code you're using will cause trouble if 2 images have the same name.

Comment: @Mr.Alien does `mysqli_error` work with `mysql_`?

Comment: @Mr.Alien `mysqli_error` does not help, because there are no calls to mysqli functions.

Comment: try to add `if (!$chkuserid ) {    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());}` after `Username = '".$myuser."'")`

Comment: you are not executing the update statement ..**Suggestion** avoid using mysql_*.. switch to PDO or mysqli_*

Comment: @Oswald Always use mysql_error, will save you time debugging your queries.

Comment: @Oswald `mysql_()` :) and @vyktor `mysql_()` remove the `i` that's it

Comment: why does people vote negatively on my posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh, you're just simply not calling `mysql_query( $sql);` in the end...

Otherwise it looks just fine. Hover you should consider using `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead of deprecated `mysql_` and make sure your code isn't vulnerable to SQL Injection.